# How to submit string in webpage using data from file

Tags: python, selenium

I have a text file with 2000 lines of strings that are each 4 characters long. I need to type each of these strings into a website's input textbox and submit them one at a time. How do I do this? I know you can fill out forms in web pages with Selenium and python, but how do you fill out a textbox using data from a text file?

Comment: you have to read the data from the file, then get the textbox element with selenium then send text to that textbox and submit

Answer (score 3):

1) Read the content of the file

2) Find the element in which you want to insert text and submit it

3) do step 2 for all lines in file

```
from selenium import webdriver

with webdriver.Firefox() as driver:
  with open('File_Name') as f:
        for line in f:
            driver.get('http://foo.com')
            element = driver.find_element_by_id('sample_element')
            element.send_keys(line.strip())
            input_element.submit()
```